# Unexpected result when comparing CharSequence.reversed() return value

Tags: kotlin

Have noticed a strange behavior when comparing a result of CharSequence.reversed() method.

```
val s = "a"
val subSequence = s.subSequence(0, 1)
println("$subSequence == ${subSequence.reversed()}: ${subSequence == subSequence.reversed()}")
```

Results in:

```
a == a: false
```

Moreover `subSequence.reversed() == subSequence.reversed()` is also `false`.

Can someone explain this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CharSequence` is actually an interface which classes like `String` and `StringBuilder` implements. The reason why the result of `subSequence(0, 1)` isn't equal to `subSequence.reversed()` is because of the actual types they return.

The `subSequence(0, 1)` call returns a `String`, while `reversed()` returns a `StringBuilder`. The equals-method will therefore return `false` because the types are different.

It will work as you would expect if you call `toString()` on the result of `reversed()`:

```
val reversed = subSequence.reversed().toString()
println("$subSequence == $reversed: ${subSequence == reversed}") // Prints a == a: true
```

Comment: String.subSequence [returns](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/sub-sequence.html) CharSequence and CharSequence.reversed() [returns](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/reversed.html) CharSequence too. Don't think it's about types.

Comment: @andrei Their return type is `CharSequence`, but the actual type of the objects that is returned is `String` and `StringBuilder`. `CharSequence` is just an interface.

Comment: You're right. My fault, missed this. And `subSequence.reversed() == subSequence.reversed()` returns `false` because `StringBuilder` doesn't override `equals` method and uses `Any`'s (comparison by reference).

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are probably confused by what is shown by [`toString`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html) and how [equality (`equals`)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html) behaves.

What you see is the output of `toString()`. Any type can decide how it's object's string representation might look like by overriding that method. This however has no influence on how objects of that type are compared against each other. That is where `equals` (in some cases also `compare`) comes in.

Others wrote something about that the underlying type of the objects to compare isn't equal (one side `StringBuilder` and the other `String`). The actual problem however is that of the `equals`-method. It could be (usually it isn't done so for various reasons), that `equals` for a certain type supports equality of different types of objects (such a behaviour (would) should be mentioned in the interface at least). If nothing is specified one can assume that the default equality from [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) holds.

In this case however the [`CharSequence`-javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) already states the following about equality (emphasis mine):

> This interface does not refine the general contracts of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. **The result of testing two objects that implement CharSequence for equality is therefore, in general, undefined**. Each object may be implemented by a different class, and thereis no guarantee that each class will be capable of testing its instancesfor equality with those of the other. It is therefore inappropriate to usearbitrary CharSequence instances as elements in a set or as keys ina map.

So summarizing: forget that you got a `String` or `StringBuilder` from `subSequence` and `reversed`. The method contract specifies `CharSequence` and as such you must handle it as `CharSequence`. There is no guarantee that those functions will still return a `String` or `StringBuilder` in future.

Answer (score 0):

Converting back to a `String` fixes the issue because then the correct (expected) `eqauals` is applied:

```
val s = "a"
val subSequence = s.subSequence(0, 1)
println(subSequence.reversed() == subSequence.reversed()) //false
println(subSequence.reversed().toString() == subSequence.reversed().toString()) //true
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct(expected)" `equals`? What's wrong with `CharSequence.equals`?

Comment: This one does not compare the way String::equals does, i.e. comparing the content in the sequence